# org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role in another environment

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, session, transactionmanager

Good day,

Know that this title is all around stack overflow and there is multiple solution as well.

But there is a bit different in this case, which I not sure where should I continue to troubleshoot.

In my `BaseUser.java` entity class, I have the following code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseUser< T extends BasePasswordHistory > extends
        AuditModel implements IDeletable, IEditable, UserProfile {

// some other code here...
        @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, mappedBy = "user")
        @OrderBy("passwordHistoryId desc")
        public Set< T > getPasswordHistories() {
            return passwordHistories;
        }
// some other code here...

}
```

And the following is part of the code I call the password history in `ManagerImpl` level, `BaseUserManagerImpl.java`.

```
 Set< T > histories = user.getPasswordHistories( );
 for ( T history : histories ) { // exception at this line in another environment
 }
```

The `BaseUserManagerImpl.java` is still under the same hibernate transaction, thus, it is able to load the `passwordHistory` object even its `lazy fetch` type. (Please correct me if I am wrong)

These code is working fine in the original environment (lets name it `env A`) , until I deploy the same code into another environment (lets name it `env B`), and it will hit `LazyInitializationException` like title.

I check for the WAS version, found that the version have some different.
[image]

Actually I dun think these is the reason to hit the exception. But I really have no idea why the same code not working in different environment. Any point I should check further?

Here I post my stacktrace:

```
2019-06-25 17:17:47.967 [WebContainer : 3] ERROR c.c.i.c.c.u.e.ExceptionHandler - [cvmaker123] - Exception occurred
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.cv.ibs.cib.support.entity.BankUser.passwordHistories, no session or session was closed
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:380) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:372) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:365) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet.iterator(PersistentSet.java:186) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at com.cv.ibs.cib.common.service.impl.BaseUserManagerImpl.verifyPasswordHistory(BaseUserManagerImpl.java:241) ~[com.cv.ibs.cib.jar:na]
    at com.cv.ibs.cib.support.service.impl.BankUserManagerImpl.updatePassword(BankUserManagerImpl.java:288) ~[com.cv.ibs.cib.jar:na]
    at com.cv.ibs.cib.support.service.impl.BankUserManagerImpl.updatePassword(BankUserManagerImpl.java:1) ~[com.cv.ibs.cib.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95) ~[na:1.7.0]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56) ~[na:1.7.0]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620) ~[na:2.6 (10-05-2016)]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309) ~[org.springframework.aop-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183) ~[org.springframework.aop-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150) ~[org.springframework.aop-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89) ~[org.springframework.aop-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[org.springframework.aop-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202) ~[org.springframework.aop-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy464.updatePassword(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at c.c.i.c.app.profile.command.ChangePasswordCommandHandler.execute(ChangePasswordCommandHandler.java:42) ~[com.cv.ibs.cib.jar:na]
```

And the following is part of the code:

```
public class ChangePasswordCommandHandler implements
        CommandHandler< ChangePasswordCommand, Integer > {

    @Autowired
    private UserManager userManager;

    public Integer execute(ChangePasswordCommand command)
            throws BaseException {

        return userManager.updatePassword( user, command.getNewPassword( ),
                command.isResetPWD( ) );
    }
}

@Service
public class UserManagerImpl extends
        BaseUserManagerImpl< User, PasswordHistory > implements
        UserManager {
    public int updatePassword(User user, String newPassword,
            boolean isResetPWD) throws BaseException {
         User entity = findById( user.getUserId( ) );
         final String newHash = getNewPasswordHash( entity, newPassword );
         entity = verifyPasswordHistory( entity, entity.getPassword( ),
                    newHash, isResetPWD );
         return 1;
     }
}

public abstract class BaseUserManagerImpl< T extends BaseUser< U >, U extends BasePasswordHistory >
        extends BaseManagerImpl< T, Long > implements BaseUserManager< T, U >,
        UserProfileService {
    final protected T verifyPasswordHistory(final T user, String oldHash,
            String newHash, boolean isResetPWD) {
        final int reuseNo = getMaxPassowrdhistory( );
        Set< U > histories = user.getPasswordHistories( );
        for ( U history : histories ) { // exception at this line in another environment
        }
    }
}
```

Kindly advise.

Comment: Can you please post the whole stacktrace?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli, just add in the stacktrace.

Comment: Can you please show the code of ChangePasswordCommandHandler.execute .BankUserManagerImpl.updatePassword BaseUserManagerImpl.verifyPasswordHistory

Comment: @SimonMartinelli, just added in the code.Kindly advise.

Comment: Try to make verifyPasswordHistory non final

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found what is wrong for this case. The WAS Java SDK for this project is pointing to Java 1.7. However, the code is compile using Java 1.6.

I found this when I check the `WAS classloader` directory. After change Java SDK in WAS Console to Java 1.7, the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Your method should be transactional at least as read only.
Do you use @Transactional annotation on top tour class or method.

Comment: Yes, I use the spring AOP to set all the class file end with *Manager will be transactional. Else it also wont work for env A. Now my env A work, but env B wont work, they are access same database.